# Making a command that shows all your cooldowns and the time remaining

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need a command that shows the list of the commands with cooldowns and the time remaining to use the command again. Is it possible especially putting the command in a cog? If yes, can you help me how to do the command?

Comment: *Is it possible?* -- Yes, it is.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński then can you show me the code and how it works if thats ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a command that shows all cooldowns is possible. You can do this with a for loop and the `is_on_cooldown()` function.

Here is an example of a command to return a list of commands and if they are on cooldown:

```py
@client.command(pass_content=True)
async def cooldowns(ctx):
  cooldown_string = ""
  for command in client.commands:
    if command.is_on_cooldown(ctx):
      cooldown_string += f"\n{command} - **Time Left:** {command.get_cooldown_retry_after(ctx)}MS"
  await ctx.send(cooldown_string)
```

From here you can add condition statements to only show commands on cooldown.

Comment: it only gives me false idk why

Comment: @jann Try running a command that has a cooldown and rerun the cooldown command right after that

Comment: wow it does but i want to show what is the time remaining to access the command again.. is it possible?

Comment: @jann Yep it is possible! You can use `command.get_cooldown_retry_after(ctx)`. I will edit it into my response to show you what I mean. If that is what you're looking for you can mark the response as accepted.

Comment: wow it does now thanks! also last thing, can i only show the commands that only have cooldown like only 5 commands will only show in the cooldown text? thanks!

`daily - 9 sec
weekly - 17 min
work - 4 min
slots - 4 min
arcade - 2 days`

Comment: @jann Yup, I've edited my response again, so now it should only show commands with an active cooldown.

Comment: it does now! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, to get all commands in cooldown and their remaining time. However, discord.py does not give direct access to it, and thus we have to abuse private class variables to get them

Code:

```py
import datetime


@client.command()
async def cooldowns(ctx: commands.Context):
    string = ""
    for command in client.walk_commands():
        dt = ctx.message.edited_at or ctx.message.created_at
        current = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
        bucket = command._buckets.get_bucket(ctx.message, current)
        if not bucket:
       continue
       retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit(current)
       if retry_after:
           string += f"{command.name} - {retry_after} Seconds\n"
       else:
           string += f"{command.name} - `READY`\n"
     string = string or "No commands are on cooldown"
     await ctx.send(string)
```

Here is what the above code will look like for commands not on cooldown:
[image]

It will follow:

command 1 - `READY`

command 2 - `READY`

...

command n - `READY` (and so on)

and, here is how it will look if commands are on cooldown:
[image]

---

### Explaining how the code works:

```py
string = ""
```

We initialize an empty string in a string variable, this is the string we will add our lines to and send it all at once.

```py
for command in bot.walk_commands():
    dt = ctx.message.edited_at or ctx.message.created_at
    current = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
    bucket = command._buckets.get_bucket(ctx.message, current)
```

`bot.walk_command()` is a method that gives us a generator object, which is essentially a generator of all the command objects the bot has stored (i.e: everything under `@bot.command()`, `@commands.command`, and `@commands.group`)

`dt` is just storing the current time the message was created at, it's a datetime object

message.created_at is a time naive offset and so we bind a timezon to it with its replace method and then we get a timestamp of that with the `timestamp()` method of `datetime.datetime` objects

all of the things we did is a waste, the third line is the meat and potatoes of what we want. `command._buckets.get_bucket` is an internal, we provide the current message object and the timestamp we created earlier.

This gives us our Cooldown object (The one you create with `@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)`, it basically yields what is inside the ()) [This is `None` for commands with no cooldowns]

here is what it looks like, just for understanding.

[image]

```py
if not bucket:
       continue
retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit(current)
if retry_after:
   string += f"{command.name} - {retry_after} Seconds\n"
else:
   string += f"{command.name} - `READY`\n"
await ctx.send(string)
```

```py
if not bucket:
       continue
```

If a bucket is not found, command does not have cooldown, meaning we can skip over it.

```py
retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit(current)
```

This basically gets us our remaining time (it's a float)
returns `None` if it's not on cooldown

```py
if retry_after:
   string += f"{command.name} - {retry_after} Seconds\n"
else:
   string += f"{command.name} - `READY`\n"
```

the if statement checks if it returned a float, if yet then command is on cooldown and we add the command name along side the cooldown time

the else is for if it's not on cooldown, then it adds the command name and `READY` along side it.

And at the end we send the entire string.

In my case, I only have one command that had cooldown, which is `spotify`.

Comment: do i need to put the @client.command() thingy? if yes where cuz it gives me an errorr...

Comment: @Jann, yes let me edit it to make it a command, one second

Comment: it doesnt work for me idk why

Comment: Rose#1328 contact me on discord please